# How to install google play services in emulator?

Tags: android, google-play-services

My sdk manger shows google play services installed but when i try to a run an application with google map its shows like 'get google play services' and crashes[image: sdk manager screen]

[image: avd]

Comment: Is it that you're not referencing the google play services library?

Comment: try this http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

Comment: @D4nC00per sorry but how to excatly refresh google play services library .My project includes google-play-services.jar